# AWS - Managing EC2 user sessions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

I have an EC2 (Windoes Server R2 2012) that is running a NodeJS process. Now, the detail is that once I get Disconnected from server (Disconnection it is supposed to keep everything on server, hence my NodeJS process) after a few minutes, the session is killed, so also the process.

I connect again and it is like I have signed out. How can I solve this? I really need to the process still running without stay ALWAYS connected to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Windows installation will not logoff disconnected sessions.

Your installation is probably customized for it to be logging off disconnected RDP sessions.

Load the Group Policy Object Editor and go to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Session Time Limits.

Check that the setting "Set time limit for disconnected sessions" is either Not Configured, or Enabled, but with a setting of Never.